# 'Manage.py behave' not recognised as command in Django project

Tags: python, django

I've had to clone a repository involving a django project.

This is my first time using django and the project is configured a bit differently than what a normal django project would be. For instance it has a settings folder with a local.py file that contains a Local(Dev) class. I have installed behave_django, however when I run the command 'manage.py behave' it says that the command is not recognised.

Therefore I believe that whilst I have added `INSTALLED_APPS = ('behave_django',)` to the `local.py` file it is not getting recognised. I have tried adding it outside the class and within. Is there a way I can run a script to check my list of installed_apps, etc. Also I am new to python and the configuration side has gotten me a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the [`--settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-settings) option so Django knows you wish to use a different settings file with your task

```
manage.py behave --settings=myapp.local
```

Comment: Another way to specify which settings file to use is to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable (ex: `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myproject.settings.local python manage.py behave`)

Comment: sudo python manage.py behave --settings=settings.local
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
ConfigError: No steps directory in ".../features"
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...

Comment: @Vitamin - That looks like your `local.py` is doing a lot more than just settings (which it really shouldn't be doing)

Comment: Ok it's now working. I had to add some directories / files to make behave run. https://pythonhosted.org/behave-django/installation.html. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I understand, however I get this without it: django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1698, "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"). I know my permissions are not right somewhere and this is another issue in itself.